# Conversion function to convert the following "11/30/2014" format to Nov-2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How to covert the following `11/30/2014` into `Nov-2014`.
`11/30/2014` is stored as varchar

Comment: mysql or sql server?

Comment: I am working on sqlserver 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution that should work even with Sql server 2005 is using [convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.90).aspx), [right](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532(v=sql.90).aspx) and [replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862(v=sql.90).aspx):

```
DECLARE @DateString char(10)= '11/30/2014'

SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(char(11), CONVERT(datetime, @DateString, 101), 106), 8), ' ', '-')
```

result: `Nov-2014`

Comment: I like this... While everybody tried to give a 2012-answer, your glass bulb's told you, that this is probably a database running on a lower level and you gave the right solution :-) upvote from my side

Comment: @Shnugo Actually, it was after reading your comment to sai on GarethD's answer... I would actually probably go with his or your solution on 2012+, since it's more readable, and upvoted both of your answers...

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(100)='11/30/2014';
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(DATE,@str,101),'MMM yyyy')
```

The `FORMAT` function was introduced with SQL-Server 2012 - very handsome...

Despite the tags you set you stated in a comment, that you are working with SQL Server 2012, so this should be OK for you...

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`TRY_CONVERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) *(To avoid breaking if you have any  invalid dates)* with the style `101` to convert to date, then [`FORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh213505.aspx) to get your desired output.

```
SELECT  FORMAT(TRY_CONVERT(DATE, '11/30/2014', 101), 'MMM-yyyy')
```

**HOWEVER** [dates should be stored as dates](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type), and [formatting should be left to the presentation layer](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/archive/2009/02/19/sql-tip-keep-your-presentation-logic-in-your-presentation-layer.aspx), so what I would do is sort out your database so that the data is stored as the appropriate type, then you can format the data in your application. This will be a bit of work upfront but will solve a lot of headaches down the road.

It is also worth noting that [`FORMAT` doesn't scale particularly well](http://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but)

Comment: We have data from XML which they have stored in sqlserver 2012 and they are storing it as varchar.:(

Comment: @sai, This is ridiculous... If you retrieve data from XML you can specify the type you are getting back. That is one of the biggest advantages...

Comment: TRY_CONVERT AND FORMAT is not a built in functions in SQL SERVER 2012

Comment: @sai Are you sure you are using SQL Server 2012? And - additionally - have a look on the databases compatibility level

Comment: i am using sqlserver 2012

Comment: @sai, Even with SQL Server 2012 a specific database may run in a lower level... You find this with right click on the database's name, options. There you chose the page "options" and you find the compatibility level. I'm not absolutely sure about the wording, my system is not english...

Comment: or: `SELECT compatibility_level
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE name = 'YourDBName' `

Comment: If it is a lower compatibility level, then I would suggest reading this - [Bad habits : Clinging to old compatibility levels](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-old-compatibility-levels/)

Answer (score 1):

```
select CONVERT(varchar,cast('11/30/2014' as date), 103)
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Your `cast` breaks on my system (german). You must ever keep in mind, that culture related formats do not work on all machines...

Comment: on executing the following query it is still showing as 11/3/2014.

Comment: 11/30/2014  should be displayed as "Nov-2014"

Comment: Then use: FORMAT(cast('11/30/2014' as date),'MMM-yyyy')